# Converting Latex format of Mathematical or scientific expressions to voice

Tags: math-mode, python, pythontex, accessibility

Text format can easily be converted into speech. Is there a way to convert Mathematical latex expression into speech?
For example

[image]

`$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$` - The fraction with numerator 1 + square root of 5 and denominator 2.

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html .

Comment: there is an ongoing discussion about Braille and audio on www-math  at the moment, including Deyan's impressive demo of audio from chrome screen reader https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-math/2021Jul/0004.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127316/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-gaussler).

Comment: @projetmbc Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks